# Pandas: More responsive syntax or function which compares value of a cell in column with previous cell and other columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have created a loop which does the job but is very inefficient in execution.

**Example Dataset:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[6039,'ABC',2],[1319,'DEF',2],[6039,'ABC',2],[2811,'DEF',2],[9256223,'XYZ',2],[7021,'ABC',3],[1302,'DEF',3],[3344,'ABC',4],[7648411,'XYZ',4],[1190,'DEF',4],[7648411,'XYZ',4],[1318,'DEF',4],[7648411,'XYZ',4],[2932,'DEF',4],[1318,'DEF',4],[7648411,'XYZ',4],[2932,'DEF',4],[1318,'DEF',4],[7648411,'XYZ',4],[2932,'XYZ',5],[1318,'DEF',5],[7648411,'XYZ',5],[2932,'DEF',5]
], columns=['A', 'B','C'])
df


     A       B  C
0   6039    ABC 2
1   1319    DEF 2
2   6039    ABC 2
3   2811    DEF 2
4   9256223 XYZ 2
5   7021    ABC 3
6   1302    DEF 3
7   3344    ABC 4
8   7648411 XYZ 4
9   1190    DEF 4
10  7648411 XYZ 4
11  1318    DEF 4
12  7648411 XYZ 4
13  2932    DEF 4
14  1318    DEF 4
15  7648411 XYZ 4
16  2932    DEF 4
17  1318    DEF 4
18  7648411 XYZ 4
19  2932    XYZ 5
20  1318    DEF 5
21  7648411 XYZ 5
22  2932    DEF 5
```

**The code I am applying:**

```
    df['D']=0
for i in range(len(df)):
        if i==0 and df["B"][i]!="XYZ":
            df.loc[i,'D']=df["A"][i]
        else:
            if df["C"][i]!=df["C"][i-1] and df["B"][i]!="XYZ":
                df['D'][i]=df["A"][i] 
            else:
                df['D'][i]=df['D'][i-1]
```

**Result:**

```
      A      B  C   D
0   6039    ABC 2   6039
1   1319    DEF 2   6039
2   6039    ABC 2   6039
3   2811    DEF 2   6039
4   9256223 XYZ 2   6039
5   7021    ABC 3   7021
6   1302    DEF 3   7021
7   3344    ABC 4   3344
8   7648411 XYZ 4   3344
9   1190    DEF 4   3344
10  7648411 XYZ 4   3344
11  1318    DEF 4   3344
12  7648411 XYZ 4   3344
13  2932    DEF 4   3344
14  1318    DEF 4   3344
15  7648411 XYZ 4   3344
16  2932    DEF 4   3344
17  1318    DEF 4   3344
18  7648411 XYZ 4   3344
19  2932    XYZ 5   3344
20  1318    DEF 5   3344
21  7648411 XYZ 5   3344
22  2932    DEF 5   3344
```

I am getting the correct result in **column D**, but the process is highly inefficient over more than 80K rows.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this? Maybe making a function and using apply method to it?

something in this format maybe?:

```
df['col_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x.col_1, x.col_2, x.col_3), axis=1)
```

I am not sure, how to apply this?

Comment: Hi, @rabta abdi I'm confused by what you're trying to do. I'd like to help, would you be more specific?

Comment: please add a [mcve]. That should make it clear to us how to help you. Also check out [ask].

Comment: Hi @NicholasPolino: All in all, I am creating a correct list in column A based on column B, column C and D are conditional points of when to take value from Column B vs taking the  previous Column A value.

Comment: Please provide some sample data, in a format that can be copy-and-pasted, and the expected output, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). A single, meaningful example is worth more than a whole essay of describing what should happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: with new input:

```py
df["D"] = df.groupby(((df.C != df.C.shift()) & (df["B"] != "XYZ")).cumsum())["A"].transform("first")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          A    B  C     D
0      6039  ABC  2  6039
1      1319  DEF  2  6039
2      6039  ABC  2  6039
3      2811  DEF  2  6039
4   9256223  XYZ  2  6039
5      7021  ABC  3  7021
6      1302  DEF  3  7021
7      3344  ABC  4  3344
8   7648411  XYZ  4  3344
9      1190  DEF  4  3344
10  7648411  XYZ  4  3344
11     1318  DEF  4  3344
12  7648411  XYZ  4  3344
13     2932  DEF  4  3344
14     1318  DEF  4  3344
15  7648411  XYZ  4  3344
16     2932  DEF  4  3344
17     1318  DEF  4  3344
18  7648411  XYZ  4  3344
19     2932  XYZ  5  3344
20     1318  DEF  5  3344
21  7648411  XYZ  5  3344
22     2932  DEF  5  3344
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I think this will do it.

```py
df.groupby(((df.C != df.C.shift()) & (df.B != 'XYZ')).cumsum()).apply(lambda frame: frame.assign(D=frame.A.iloc[0]))
```

The complex condition sets boolean flags at every position where a new `C` value occurs as long as `B` is not `XYZ`. We turn that into groups with `cumsum` and et voila. For the `.apply()` part, Andrej Keseley's `.transform("first")` solution is much more elegant.

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't get me to exact results.
 Results through the code:

`A B C D`    
`0 6039 ABC 2 6039.0`
`1 1319 DEF 2 6039.0`
`2 6039 ABC 2 NaN`
`3 2811 DEF 2 NaN`
`4 9256223 XYZ 2 NaN`
`5 7021 ABC 3 7021.0`
`6 1302 DEF 3 7021.0`
`7 3344 ABC 4 3344.0`
`8 7648411 XYZ 4 3344.0`
`9 1190 DEF 4 NaN`
`10 7648411 XYZ 4 NaN`
`11 1318 DEF 4 NaN`
`12 7648411 XYZ 4 NaN`
`13 2932 DEF 4 NaN`

Comment: Nice edit! Could it be that you actually want to take all groups of `C` and turn `D` the first value of `A` from that group?

Comment: Yes, only if when new group of C starts, Group B should not be "XYZ", if it is, group A should continue as is.

Comment: Ok, so `df.groupby('C').apply(lambda frame: frame.assign(D=frame.A.iloc[0]))` won't do it?

Comment: No it is not doing it. Though, If I keep on re-running this command over and over again, the Nans do fill up over time with needed values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247089/discussion-between-fsimonjetz-and-rabta-abdi).